# .Net project runtime with NuGet HDF5DotNet x86 can't find 'HDF5DotNet.dll' on VirtualBox Windows 10, but runs ok on Windows 10 laptop

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio, hdf5

My windows form .NET app with NuGet HDF5DotNetx86 works perfect on physical Windows 10 laptop but the exact same project gets this error on VitualBox Windows 10 running atop Ubuntu.

Runs ok on physical Windows 10 laptop remotely running same project directory on VirtualBox Windows 10.

Both laptops are updated Windows 10 Pro.
[image]

ERROR DETAILS...

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException   HResult=0x8007007E   Message=Could
>   not load file or assembly 'HDF5DotNet.dll' or one of its dependencies.
>   The specified module could not be found.   Source=HEATMAP project
>   StackTrace:    at HDF5_file.read_color_table(String
>   color_table_pathname, Double[,]& color_table_dataset) in
>   C:\PRIMARY\WORK\SYSTEM HUB - LATEST\HEATMAP project\HDF5_file.cs:line
>   1047    at
>   WindowsApp1.RF_Heatmap_XY_birdseye.heatmap_window_Load(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) in C:\PRIMARY\WORK\SYSTEM HUB -
>   LATEST\SOURCE\RF_Heatmap_XY_birdseye.vb:line 43    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd,
>   Int32 msg, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.Show()

Here is location of the .DLL
[image]

"Could not load file or assembly 'HDF5DotNet.dll' or one of its dependencies."
What would those dependencies be?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?